# Is it possible to trace a Drupal PHP session variable and if so, how?

Tags: 7, caching, debugging, sessions

I'm having an issue with Drupal not caching pages and I think it's being caused by an active PHP session variable being set for anonymous users. I want to know if it's possible to quickly and/or easily find out which module/theme/random piece of code is setting the variable?

Comment: Not really. Since any module is free to modify the session at arbitrary points, you have no guarantees for any particular behavior. (That's global scope for you, thanks, Drupal). What I would do is find the variable name with firebug, and start grepping the code base for that.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. The cookie is named "SESSf00468401b897bf4b23b3f8bc642c33e" so I'm assuming that it's just made on the fly. I might start dropping code into the core session handling functions to see if I can trace it that way.

Comment: That's the normal drupal session cookie name, so search for $SESSION in your code

Comment: $_SESSION, maybe;)